# Filling empty Numpy array with numbers

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have created a numpy array with (16,19) dimension. I would like to fill it with ones in the first row, 2 in the second row, 3 in the third row and so on until I reach the last row.
I am very new in Python so that´s why I don´t probabably understand very well how it works. This is what I have tried until now:

```
arboles=np.zeros((16,19),dtype=np.int16)

for i in arboles:
    count=0
    arboli = arboles[1,:] == 1
    arboles=count+1
```

I am probably missing some order in the middle where I ask Numpy to write the numbers in the empty array. Any help please?

Comment: Use `enumerate` and fill it with an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like each row to be filled with the row's id in the array, you can do:

```
arboles=np.zeros((16,19),dtype=np.int16)

for row in range(0, arboles.shape[0]):
    arboles[row, :] = row
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. Is it possible to start filling the rows with 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Sure, all you need to do is to have: `for row in range(1, arboles.shape[0]+1):` !

Comment: I have tried this new piece of code but I get the same result as before, the first row is still 0.

Comment: Sorry you're right. It nees to be : `for row in range(1, arboles.shape[0]+1): arboles[row-1, :] = row`.